# How do I rate limit the beta HTTP Api from AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

How do I rate limit the [beta HTTP Api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api.html) from AWS API Gateway

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html), Usage plans and API keys are not supported for HTTP APIs. That probably indicates that setting throttle and burst limits is also not possible with HTTP APIs.

To verify this, I tried to update the stage of my HTTP API using [update-stage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigatewayv2/update-stage.html) AWS CLI command as below -

```
$ aws apigatewayv2 update-stage --api-id $API_ID --stage-name $STAGE_NAME --default-route-settings ThrottlingRateLimit=1000


An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the UpdateStage operation: Route-level throttling settings are not supported on protocolType HTTP
```

Like you already know, HTTP APIs are in beta and have very limited features at this moment; the goal of using them is lower cost and performance optimization.

UPDATE: Information on account and route-level throttling for HTTP APIs can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-protect.html).

Comment: While your answer is useful, my intention in the question was to garner ways in which how would one rate limit the beta api despite the lack of inbuilt support.

Comment: You'll have to use a proxy in front - could be a Cloudfront distribution, NGINX server or using AWS WAF to set up rate based rules. I haven't tried it but I think sticking to REST API would be just easier for now.

Answer (score 0):

beta HTTP api is pretty much non-functional atm, would stick to the original REST one for now